# Uploading a structured HTML/formatted document to Google Docs API

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I am uploading content to Google Docs using the api. The doc is in plain HTML and I am wanting to convert the tags into the formatting that docs uses, i.e. H1 becomes Heading 1, H2 becomes Heading 2, etc.

I had thought that this conversion would happen naturally, but when you look at the created document in Docs it has lost all of its structure. I can't see anything in the documentation relating to maintaining formatting, or identifying a syntax we might use to tell docs of the intended status of a piece of text.

Has anyone else had any success with this?

Code used to generate the document (Python):

```
this_document=gdata.data.MediaSource(file_handle=this_html_string,content_type='text/html',content_length=this_html_string_length)

this_new_doc=this_gdoc.Upload(this_document, this_title, content_type='text/html')
```

Comment: Using Docs frequently without API, I have at some point wondered how to import Content from web pages. Copy&Paste definitely doesn't really work, it gives ugly results.

But the explanation is simple: Docs has only very basic layouting, e.g. you cannot cascade tables. Actually it is a very annoying task to make tables not as wide as the screen.

Anyways I suggest you play around with copy and paste to see the capabilities and then check back with the API.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: It just started working at some point. I suspect that the HTML wasn't properly formed: I'm passing in a full HTML doc, rather than just the contents of the body.

Comment: @notreadbyhumans so you got it to work and keep the html/css formatting? I am facing the same problem now.